# Getting ongoing recording data segments from AVAudioRecorder

Tags: cocoa-touch, audio, nsdata, avaudiorecorder

My problem is as follows:

I need to capture every **320 bytes** of raw audio data.
I do this by using an NSTimer that fires a method every 0.02 seconds - that is because i need to record 8000Hz and 16bit mono audio, and i've calculated that it should be 50x a second (8000 * 16 / 320 / 8).

So, knowing that the `AVAudioRecorder` saves to a file, i can get every **320 bytes** from that file by `[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[audioRecorder url]] subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(bytesUsed, 320)]`, but the thing that has confused me, is that the moment i start the recording, the data files size is **4096 bytes** and then after 0.5 seconds, it's **9424 bytes** and increases by around 5,3k bytes every half a second.

So i'm confused if i'm getting the right data and thinking that the settings might be wrong.
Current settings for `AVAudioRecorder` are:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,  
[NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,  
[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,  
[NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,  
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,  
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
```

So the main problem is:
**What settings should i use?**
**Is this the right way to go about getting segments from an ongoing audio recording?**

I apologize for the bad explanation, do ask questions to help me make it more understandable.